# is the machine code fed into CPU all the time as program works

Tags: cpu

I do not know how to say what I try to say but I will ask it as much openly as I can. What I wonder is that imagine you write some java code in eclipse and you press run and some machine code is generated and is sent to CPU and you see the desired output. Is that machine code sent over and over and over to CPU as long as the program you write does what is supposed to do or is machine code sent to CPU just once?

Answer (score 1):

As always, the full truth is pretty nuanced and with many footnotes, but... in a **VERY** simplified way, neither:

The machine code is put into **memory**. The CPU fetches it from there, one instruction after another, and executes them. If the same instruction needs to be executed multiple times (like inside a loop), it will be fetched multiple times.

The CPU itself has very little memory, and it only keeps track of the one instruction it executes. After its done, it "forgets" it and fetches the next one. So your machine code isn't "sent" to the CPU at all. Instead the CPU "fetches" it piece-by-piece as it is executing it.

Comment: @runo - Just keep in mind that this is how computers worked, like, 40 years ago. Today there are a lot more tricks involved to speed things up - CPU caches, execution pipelines, branch prediction, instruction can be executed in the wrong order, etc, etc. But all this is done very very carefully to give an illusion as if everything still works the way I described above.